# Compute least-cost matrix between all pairs of destination using GRASS v.net.allpairs (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, cost-path, least-cost

I have a vector line shapefile showing the road network in a particular country with data on the unit cost for each line. I also have a point shapefile showing the centroids of each district in the country. There are 139 such centroids.

I am trying to compute the cost of the least cost path for all pairs of district centroids. I try to use v.netallpairs in QGIS to do this. However, I get the warning message: "139 points found, but not requested to be exported. Verify 'type' parameter". In the output, I get about 1000 paths instead of 139C2=9591 pairs. I am not sure whether this has to do with the fact that some centroids are far from a road (I try increasing the threshold for connection to no avail), the fact that there is no index column for the district centroids or I have not specified some option correctly.

I will prefer a QGIS GUI-based solution.

Comment: If you wish to also seek ArcMap, ArcGIS Pro or R solutions then please do that in a separate question for each.